# Toastr notifications not showing on bottom right

Tags: javascript, html, css, toastr

I am trying to use Toastr notifications (https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr). They work fine, but the problem is that they only appear at the top right. I can change anything about the position, but they will always show at the top right. I found a few people with the same problem, but the solutions did not work for me.

Can somebody please check my code, if there is any way of correcting this?

```js
/*
 * Toastr
 * Copyright 2012-2014 John Papa and Hans Fjällemark.
 * All Rights Reserved.
 * Use, reproduction, distribution, and modification of this code is subject to the terms and
 * conditions of the MIT license, available at http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * Author: John Papa and Hans Fjällemark
 * ARIA Support: Greta Krafsig
 * Project: https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr
 */
; (function (define) {
    define(['jquery'], function ($) {
        return (function () {
            var $container;
            var listener;
            var toastId = 0;
            var toastType = {
                error: 'error',
                info: 'info',
                success: 'success',
                warning: 'warning'
            };

            var toastr = {
                clear: clear,
                remove: remove,
                error: error,
                getContainer: getContainer,
                info: info,
                options: {},
                subscribe: subscribe,
                success: success,
                version: '2.0.3',
                warning: warning
            };

            return toastr;

            //#region Accessible Methods
            function error(message, title, optionsOverride) {
                return notify({
                    type: toastType.error,
                    iconClass: getOptions().iconClasses.error,
                    message: message,
                    optionsOverride: optionsOverride,
                    title: title
                });
            }

            function getContainer(options, create) {
                if (!options) { options = getOptions(); }
                $container = $('#' + options.containerId);
                if ($container.length) {
                    return $container;
                }
                if(create) {
                    $container = createContainer(options);
                }
                return $container;
            }

            function info(message, title, optionsOverride) {
                return notify({
                    type: toastType.info,
                    iconClass: getOptions().iconClasses.info,
                    message: message,
                    optionsOverride: optionsOverride,
                    title: title
                });
            }

            function subscribe(callback) {
                listener = callback;
            }

            function success(message, title, optionsOverride) {
                return notify({
                    type: toastType.success,
                    iconClass: getOptions().iconClasses.success,
                    message: message,
                    optionsOverride: optionsOverride,
                    title: title
                });
            }

            function warning(message, title, optionsOverride) {
                return notify({
                    type: toastType.warning,
                    iconClass: getOptions().iconClasses.warning,
                    message: message,
                    optionsOverride: optionsOverride,
                    title: title
                });
            }

            function clear($toastElement) {
                var options = getOptions();
                if (!$container) { getContainer(options); }
                if (!clearToast($toastElement, options)) {
                    clearContainer(options);
                }
            }

            function remove($toastElement) {
                var options = getOptions();
                if (!$container) { getContainer(options); }
                if ($toastElement && $(':focus', $toastElement).length === 0) {
                    removeToast($toastElement);
                    return;
                }
                if ($container.children().length) {
                    $container.remove();
                }
            }
            //#endregion

            //#region Internal Methods

            function clearContainer(options){
                var toastsToClear = $container.children();
                for (var i = toastsToClear.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    clearToast($(toastsToClear[i]), options);
                };
            }

            function clearToast($toastElement, options){
                if ($toastElement && $(':focus', $toastElement).length === 0) {
                    $toastElement[options.hideMethod]({
                        duration: options.hideDuration,
                        easing: options.hideEasing,
                        complete: function () { removeToast($toastElement); }
                    });
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            function createContainer(options) {
                $container = $('<div/>')
                    .attr('id', options.containerId)
                    .addClass(options.positionClass)
                    .attr('aria-live', 'polite')
                    .attr('role', 'alert');

                $container.appendTo($(options.target));
                return $container;
            }

            function getDefaults() {
                return {
                    tapToDismiss: true,
                    toastClass: 'toast',
                    containerId: 'toast-container',
                    debug: false,

                    showMethod: 'fadeIn', //fadeIn, slideDown, and show are built into jQuery
                    showDuration: 300,
                    showEasing: 'swing', //swing and linear are built into jQuery
                    onShown: undefined,
                    hideMethod: 'fadeOut',
                    hideDuration: 1000,
                    hideEasing: 'swing',
                    onHidden: undefined,

                    extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                    iconClasses: {
                        error: 'toast-error',
                        info: 'toast-info',
                        success: 'toast-success',
                        warning: 'toast-warning'
                    },
                    iconClass: 'toast-info',
                    positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
                    timeOut: 5000, // Set timeOut and extendedTimeout to 0 to make it sticky
                    titleClass: 'toast-title',
                    messageClass: 'toast-message',
                    target: 'body',
                    closeHtml: '<button>&times;</button>',
                    newestOnTop: true
                };
            }

            function publish(args) {
                if (!listener) { return; }
                listener(args);
            }

            function notify(map) {
                var options = getOptions(),
                    iconClass = map.iconClass || options.iconClass;

                if (typeof (map.optionsOverride) !== 'undefined') {
                    options = $.extend(options, map.optionsOverride);
                    iconClass = map.optionsOverride.iconClass || iconClass;
                }

                toastId++;

                $container = getContainer(options, true);
                var intervalId = null,
                    $toastElement = $('<div/>'),
                    $titleElement = $('<div/>'),
                    $messageElement = $('<div/>'),
                    $closeElement = $(options.closeHtml),
                    response = {
                        toastId: toastId,
                        state: 'visible',
                        startTime: new Date(),
                        options: options,
                        map: map
                    };

                if (map.iconClass) {
                    $toastElement.addClass(options.toastClass).addClass(iconClass);
                }

                if (map.title) {
                    $titleElement.append(map.title).addClass(options.titleClass);
                    $toastElement.append($titleElement);
                }

                if (map.message) {
                    $messageElement.append(map.message).addClass(options.messageClass);
                    $toastElement.append($messageElement);
                }

                if (options.closeButton) {
                    $closeElement.addClass('toast-close-button').attr("role", "button");
                    $toastElement.prepend($closeElement);
                }

                $toastElement.hide();
                if (options.newestOnTop) {
                    $container.prepend($toastElement);
                } else {
                    $container.append($toastElement);
                }


                $toastElement[options.showMethod](
                    { duration: options.showDuration, easing: options.showEasing, complete: options.onShown }
                );

                if (options.timeOut > 0) {
                    intervalId = setTimeout(hideToast, options.timeOut);
                }

                $toastElement.hover(stickAround, delayedHideToast);
                if (!options.onclick && options.tapToDismiss) {
                    $toastElement.click(hideToast);
                }

                if (options.closeButton && $closeElement) {
                    $closeElement.click(function (event) {
                        if( event.stopPropagation ) {
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        } else if( event.cancelBubble !== undefined && event.cancelBubble !== true ) {
                            event.cancelBubble = true;
                        }
                        hideToast(true);
                    });
                }

                if (options.onclick) {
                    $toastElement.click(function () {
                        options.onclick();
                        hideToast();
                    });
                }

                publish(response);

                if (options.debug && console) {
                    console.log(response);
                }

                return $toastElement;

                function hideToast(override) {
                    if ($(':focus', $toastElement).length && !override) {
                        return;
                    }
                    return $toastElement[options.hideMethod]({
                        duration: options.hideDuration,
                        easing: options.hideEasing,
                        complete: function () {
                            removeToast($toastElement);
                            if (options.onHidden && response.state !== 'hidden') {
                                options.onHidden();
                            }
                            response.state = 'hidden';
                            response.endTime = new Date();
                            publish(response);
                        }
                    });
                }

                function delayedHideToast() {
                    if (options.timeOut > 0 || options.extendedTimeOut > 0) {
                        intervalId = setTimeout(hideToast, options.extendedTimeOut);
                    }
                }

                function stickAround() {
                    clearTimeout(intervalId);
                    $toastElement.stop(true, true)[options.showMethod](
                        { duration: options.showDuration, easing: options.showEasing }
                    );
                }
            }

            function getOptions() {
                return $.extend({}, getDefaults(), toastr.options);
            }

            function removeToast($toastElement) {
                if (!$container) { $container = getContainer(); }
                if ($toastElement.is(':visible')) {
                    return;
                }
                $toastElement.remove();
                $toastElement = null;
                if ($container.children().length === 0) {
                    $container.remove();
                }
            }
            //#endregion

        })();
    });
}(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define : function (deps, factory) {
    if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) { //Node
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        window['toastr'] = factory(window['jQuery']);
    }
}));
```

```css
.toast-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.toast-message {
  -ms-word-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.toast-message a,
.toast-message label {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.toast-message a:hover {
  color: #cccccc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.toast-close-button {
  position: relative;
  right: -0.3em;
  top: -0.3em;
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.toast-close-button:hover,
.toast-close-button:focus {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.4;
  -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40);
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}
/*Additional properties for button version
 iOS requires the button element instead of an anchor tag.
 If you want the anchor version, it requires `href="#"`.*/
button.toast-close-button {
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.toast-top-center {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.toast-bottom-center {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.toast-top-full-width {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.toast-bottom-full-width {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.toast-top-left {
  top: 12px;
  left: 12px;
}
.toast-top-right {
  top: 12px;
  right: 12px;
}
.toast-bottom-right {
  right: 12px;
  bottom: 12px;
}
.toast-bottom-left {
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 12px;
}
#toast-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999;
  pointer-events: none;
  /*overrides*/
}
#toast-container * {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#toast-container > div {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 6px;
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
  width: 300px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
  background-position: 15px center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #999999;
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=80);
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
#toast-container > :hover {
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 12px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px #000000;
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#toast-container > .toast-info {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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") !important;
}
#toast-container > .toast-error {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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") !important;
}
#toast-container > .toast-success {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAADsSURBVEhLY2AYBfQMgf///3P8+/evAIgvA/FsIF+BavYDDWMBGroaSMMBiE8VC7AZDrIFaMFnii3AZTjUgsUUWUDA8OdAH6iQbQEhw4HyGsPEcKBXBIC4ARhex4G4BsjmweU1soIFaGg/WtoFZRIZdEvIMhxkCCjXIVsATV6gFGACs4Rsw0EGgIIH3QJYJgHSARQZDrWAB+jawzgs+Q2UO49D7jnRSRGoEFRILcdmEMWGI0cm0JJ2QpYA1RDvcmzJEWhABhD/pqrL0S0CWuABKgnRki9lLseS7g2AlqwHWQSKH4oKLrILpRGhEQCw2LiRUIa4lwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==") !important;
}
#toast-container > .toast-warning {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,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") !important;
}
#toast-container.toast-top-center > div,
#toast-container.toast-bottom-center > div {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#toast-container.toast-top-full-width > div,
#toast-container.toast-bottom-full-width > div {
  width: 96%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.toast {
  background-color: #030303;
}
.toast-success {
  background-color: #51a351;
}
.toast-error {
  background-color: #bd362f;
}
.toast-info {
  background-color: #2f96b4;
}
.toast-warning {
  background-color: #f89406;
}
.toast-progress {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.4;
  -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40);
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}
/*Responsive Design*/
@media all and (max-width: 240px) {
  #toast-container > div {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 50px;
    width: 11em;
  }
  #toast-container .toast-close-button {
    right: -0.2em;
    top: -0.2em;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 241px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  #toast-container > div {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 50px;
    width: 18em;
  }
  #toast-container .toast-close-button {
    right: -0.2em;
    top: -0.2em;
  }
}
@media all and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  #toast-container > div {
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 50px;
    width: 25em;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Toastr</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
 <link href="build/toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="toastr.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Toastr</h1>
</div>

<!-- Toastr -->
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout('first()', 3000);
function first()
{
Command: toastr["success"]("Are you the six fingered man?")

toastr.options = {
  "closeButton": false,
  "debug": false,
  "newestOnTop": false,
  "progressBar": false,
  "positionClass": "toast-bottom-right",
  "preventDuplicates": false,
  "onclick": null,
  "showDuration": "300",
  "hideDuration": "1000",
  "timeOut": "5000",
  "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
  "showEasing": "swing",
  "hideEasing": "linear",
  "showMethod": "fadeIn",
  "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
}
}
</script>
<!-- Toastr -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, if i only try to show it on the left, it doesn't work as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Toastr</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Toastr bottom test</h1>
    </div>

    
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {

        function Toast(type, css, msg) {
            this.type = type;
            this.css = css;
            this.msg = 'This is positioned in the ' + msg + '. You can also style the icon any way you like.';
        }

        var toasts = [
            new Toast('error', 'toast-bottom-full-width', 'This is positioned in the bottom full width. You can also style the icon any way you like.'),
            new Toast('info', 'toast-top-full-width', 'top full width'),
            new Toast('warning', 'toast-top-left', 'This is positioned in the top left. You can also style the icon any way you like.'),
            new Toast('success', 'toast-top-right', 'top right'),
            new Toast('warning', 'toast-bottom-right', 'bottom right'),
            new Toast('error', 'toast-bottom-left', 'bottom left')
        ];

        toastr.options.positionClass = 'toast-top-full-width';
        toastr.options.extendedTimeOut = 0; //1000;
        toastr.options.timeOut = 1000;
        toastr.options.fadeOut = 250;
        toastr.options.fadeIn = 250;

        var i = 0;

        delayToasts();

        function delayToasts() {
            if (i === toasts.length) { return; }
            var delay = i === 0 ? 0 : 2100;
            window.setTimeout(function () { showToast(); }, delay);

            // re-enable the button        
            if (i === toasts.length-1) {
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#tryMe').prop('disabled', false);
                    i = 0;
                }, delay + 1000);
            }
        }

        function showToast() {
            var t = toasts[i];
            toastr.options.positionClass = t.css;
            toastr[t.type](t.msg);
            i++;
            delayToasts();
        }
    })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to make it as i did, so that there could be more than just one toast notificcation at a time?